# Significance of Time constants in LR and RC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, time, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

What is the significance of a time constant in a circuit? Is there any use of knowing the time at which the charge in a capacitor is 1-1/e times its total charge? 
What is special about the capacitor having 63% of total charge?
(I know how to find time constant)

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what research you've already done. For example have you read the [Wikipedia article on the RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: 1) my text book didn't say anything apart from how to find it. 2) Wikipedia says it's the product of net resistance across the circuit and capacitance, which I understood. I am still unable to understand the importance it's given. What can you do when you know the time constant? (Apart from knowing the capacitor is 63% full.)

Comment: The time constant $T$, the final charge on the capacitor $Q_{\infty}$ and the initial charging rate $I(0)$ are related by $I(0)=Q_{\infty}/T$. So if the capacitor continued charging at the initial rate $I(0)$ then it would take time constant $T$ to reach the final charge.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, it takes infinite time to charge a capacitor. So, the time when the capacitor is 100% charged never comes. Thus, we require a Time Constant to help us understand the time when the capacitor has got a decent amount of charge and after which the rate of charging becomes really slow and thus charging further is not of much use.

You may also think of it in another way : 
*All Electrical or Electronic circuits or systems suffer from some form of “time-delay” between its input and output, when a signal or voltage, either continuous, ( DC ) or alternating ( AC ) is firstly applied to it. This delay is generally known as the time delay or Time Constant of the circuit and it is the time response of the circuit when a step voltage or signal is firstly applied.* -ElectronicsTutorials (source).